# requests.get выдает неполную html страницу

Tags: post, requests, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно достать названия товаров, вот сайт https://inkafarma.pe/categoria/salud/problemas-digestivos Пробовал передать в requests.get heeaders, не помогло. как я понял сервер подгружает мне скрипты при прокрутке вниз. когда открыл network появились файлы filtered-products  с методом post, в request payload меняется page. В связи с этим у меня вопрос, как из этих файлов взять названия товаров или есть другой метод?

Comment: Пожайлуста ответьте помог я вам или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Selenium(С помощью его можно что угодно парсить).И когда вам надо будет что-то прогрузить, с помощью специальних команд скрольте сайт и собирайте информацию.

Comment: Нету кода так как в этом вопросе нет конкретной ошибки и  задачи, если вы конкретизируйте свой вопрос, и напишите что вам надо спарсить я изменю свой ответ

Comment: я пробовал селениум, получал html страницу абсолютно такую же